# SQL search for string within string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a search function on my site that will return strings within strings. For example: if there was a record in the SQL database where a column's value was "My name is Harry Potter", then the user could search for "Harry P" or "ott" or "My Name", and the record would come up in the search results.

Comment: You should at least accept the answer when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

use this in your SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title LIKE '%$search_word%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)** function.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myName LIKE '%Harry P%'

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myName LIKE '%ott%'

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myName LIKE '%My Name%'
```

Here I have assume `myName` is the field name that you have in your database & `myTable` is the table name.

In PHP, your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myName LIKE '%$yourWord%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table is / will be small, then a statement with `LIKE '%word%'` will be fine.

Although you might be tempted to use a MyISAM table to be able to use a Fulltext index, [this is possible in InnoDB too](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/231902587). It will be a bit harder to implement it this way, but it will combine the high-performance text searching that MyISAM offers with all the benefits of InnoDB (transactions, row-level locking etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where instr(some_column, 'string_to_search') > 0
```